# How to compile linux executable on windows machine using mingw?

Tags: linux, windows, gcc, g++, mingw

I'm trying to make my c++ project cross compiled from all machines and to all machines, so I found that minGW can compile windows executable on linux, but can the opposite be done ? so compiling LINUX executable from windows machine ?

I successfully installed minGW on linux/Mac but I didn't found any tutorial on doing same thing from windows.

Comment: Just install WSL or set up a VM and use that.

Comment: use https://travis-ci.org/

Comment: Thanks @Shawn this is good solution.

Comment: Thanks @MichałWalenciak, but this solution is not suitable for me, I need off-line compiler not a web service.